# how to compare previous node value in xslt 1.1?

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
<pre><getPolicystatus>
<agentno>001</agentno>
<policynumber>1</policynumber><req><req1>age</req1><status>success</status></req><req><req1>test</req1><status>failure</status></req><req><req1>health</req1><status>success</status></req></policyresult>
<policyresult><agentno>001</agentno>
<policynumber>1</policynumber><req><req1>age</req1><status>success</status></req><req><req1>test</req1><status>failure</status></req><req><req1>health</req1><status>success</status></req></policyresult>
<policyresult><agentno>002</agentno>
<policynumber>1</policynumber><req><req1>age</req1><status>success</status></req><req><req1>test</req1><status>failure</status></req><req><req1>health</req1><status>success</status></req></policyresult></getPolicystatus>
</pre>
```

I have a XML something like the above. I need to display the output like below
based upon the agent number. If the  agent number is repeated we need to skip that number.

```
001

1agesuccesstestfailurehealthsuccess
1agesuccesstestfailurehealthsuccess

002

1agesuccesstestfailurehealthsuccess
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an XML file at all. Please fix your question!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (a) that there is a start-tag for policyresult missing at the end of the first line of your sample XML, and (b) that what you mean is that you want, in XSLT 1.0, to process every policyresult element whose agentno child differs from the agentno child of its immediately preceding sibling, then the simplest approach is to write two templates for policyresult.

One will handle the case where the element should be displayed:

```
<xsl:template match="policyresult">
  <!--* contents left as exercise for the reader ... *-->
</xsl:template>
```

The other will handle the case where the element should be suppressed:

```
<xsl:template match="policyresult
  [agentno = ../preceding-sibling::policyresult[1]/agentno]"/>
```

If on the other hand (b') policyresult should be suppressed if its agentno matches *any* preceding agent number, not just the one in the immediately preceding policyresult element, then suppress the `[1]` in the second match pattern.

[*Addendum*]

These two templates, together with the others you write, will go together inside the XSL stylesheet you are writing, so you'll have something more or less like the following:

```
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="policyresult">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="agentno"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="policyresult
  [agentno = preceding-sibling::policyresult[1]/agentno]">
    <xsl:message>Suppressing duplicate policyresult ...</xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="agentno"/>
  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are just beginning with XSLT, I strongly recommend you get a good tutorial introduction and work through it.  XSLT is different enough from other programming languages that just bluffing your way through is unlikely to lead to happy results.

Comment: can you please provide me the exact xsl code as iam getting xpath invalid error when iam using above given code

Comment: i am very new to the xsl that's y i am asking the sample code..how to call that second code that you have given..

Comment: <getPolicystatus> is the root tag for my xml